# How to view LINQ Generated SQL statements?

Tags: linq

How is it done using the ObjectQuery method?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is what I found using ObjectQuery Method. Using console for testing, you can do the following:

Create an Extension Method as below, then call it. Say Product product, then SQL prints out as product.ToTraceString.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToTraceString<T>(this IQueryable<T> t)
    {
        string sql = "";
        ObjectQuery<T> oqt = t as ObjectQuery<T>;
        if (oqt != null)
            sql = oqt.ToTraceString();
        return sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be used in VS Watch window too:
`((ObjectQuery)myQuery).ToTraceString()`. Nice one!

Comment: What about aggregate methods like `Count`?

Comment: I don't think works when using dbContext as you can't cast IQueryable<T> to ObjectQuery<T> in this case.

Answer (score 69):

You can always attach something to the .Log property of your DataContext. That will show all the SQL commands as they are sent.

I do this in my base for data access objects and output it to the Visual Studio debug console. As the objects create their DataContext I check it see if its debug and attach a TextWritter helper class like this:

```
dbDataContext _dB = new dbDataContext();
_dB.CommandTimeout = 5000;

#if DEBUG
    _dB.Log = new DebugTextWriter();
#endif
```

Here is the helper object for output to the debug console:

```
//utility class for output of TextWriter for the Visual Sudio Debug window
class DebugTextWriter : System.IO.TextWriter
{
    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(new String(buffer, index, count));
    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(value);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.Default; }
    }
}
```

Comment: For those using **Entity Framework 6** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20751723/2218697), hope helps someone.

Comment: you can just use `context.Log = Console.Out;` it's way simpler

Answer (score 21):

You could have a look at the [Linq-to-SQL Debug Visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx), or just hover your mouse over your Linq-to-SQL query (tooltip should show generated SQL), or access:

```
context.GetCommand(query).CommandText
```

Comment: I haven't tried that GetCommand yet. I like the link from Scott Gu! Is that Visualizer built-in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @nellbryant: no, it's still a separate extension that you need to grab from the VS gallery

Answer (score 20):

```
 var q = from img in context.Images
                    ...
         select img;
 string sql = q.ToString();
```

`sql` will contain the sql select query.

**EDIT: disadvantage:** parameters won't have any values at this time

Comment: If you're debugging locally and using SQL Server, run the SQL Profiler. The query with all parameters will show up there.

Answer (score 7):

You could run the SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: If you use SQL profiler, to ensure capture of all LINQ queries from your VS debug session, use SQL Profiler 'RPC Completed' and 'SQL:BatchCompleted' events.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I use when setting up the database context:

```
this.DbContext.Database.Log += s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are executing the linq query against a database, you can run the SQL Profiler to record the SQL query that is being executed. We do it quite often to identify any performance impact on conversion.

Answer (score 1):

just a small update you can now use an Action to log the SQL:

```
// test SQL logger
Action<string> SQLLogger = (message) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(message);
_dB.Context().Database.Log = SQLLogger;
```

Answer (score 0):

In versions >= EF Core 5.0, You can use ToQueryString method on IQueryable.

```
public static string ToQueryString(this IQueryable source)
```

Example:

```
var sql = context.Blogs
.OrderBy(b => b.BlogId)
.ToQueryString();
```

You will get result as shown below.

```
SELECT [b].[BlogId], [b].[Discriminator], [b].[Url], [b].[RssUrl]
FROM [Blogs] AS [b]
ORDER BY [b].[BlogId]
```