# How this linq execute?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

```
Data = _db.ALLOCATION_D.OrderBy(a => a.ALLO_ID)
                       .Skip(10)
                       .Take(10)
                       .ToList();
```

Let say I have 100000 rows in `ALLOCATION_D` table. I want to select first 10 row. Now I want to know how the above statement executes. I don't know but I think it executes in the following way...

1. first it select the 100000 rows
2. then ordered by ALLO_ID
3. then Skip 10
4. finally select the 10 rows.

Is it right? I want to know more details.

Comment: Look at which SQL it generated. That's exactly how it executes.

Comment: How to see which sql it generates? will be highly pleased if kindly tell me the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Linq produce a SQL query via Entity Framework. Then it depends on your DBMS, but for SQL Server 2008, here is the query produces:

```
SELECT TOP (10) [Extent1].[ALLO_ID] AS [ALLO_ID],   
FROM ( 
    SELECT [Extent1].[ALLO_ID] AS [ALLO_ID]
         , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[ALLO_ID] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[ALLOCATION_D] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 10
ORDER BY [Extent1].[ALLO_ID] ASC
```

You can run this in your C# for retrieve the query:

```
var linqQuery = _db.ALLOCATION_D
                   .OrderBy(a => a.ALLO_ID)
                   .Skip(10)
                   .Take(10);
var sqlQuery = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)linqQuery).ToTraceString();
Data = linqQuery.ToList();
```

Second option with Linq To SQL

```
var linqQuery = _db.ALLOCATION_D
                   .OrderBy(a => a.ALLO_ID)
                   .Skip(10)
                   .Take(10);
var sqlQuery = _db.GetCommand(linqQuery).CommandText;
Data = linqQuery.ToList();
```

References:

- [How do I view the SQL generated by the entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)
- [How to: Display Generated SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx)
- [How to view LINQ Generated SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899974/how-to-view-linq-generated-sql-statements)

Comment: how can i see it from oracle

Comment: Run the C# code I give you, it is not dependant on your DBMS.

Comment: I ran it and got exception.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[InceptaProto.Entities.ALLOCATION_D]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement reads as follows:

1. Select all rows (overwritten by skip/take)
2. Order by Allo_ID
3. Order by Allo_ID again
4. Skip first 10 rows
5. Take next 10 rows

If you want it to select the **first** ten rows, you simply do this:

```
 Data = _db.ALLOCATION_D // You don't need to order twice
                    .OrderBy(a => a.ALLO_ID)
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToList()
```

Comment: why Order by ALLO_ID two times?

Comment: Because you have two OrderBy's in your question.

Comment: no its not the answer. I explained it already in my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Up to the `ToList` call, the calls only generates expressions. That means that the `OrderBy`, `Skip` and `Take` calls are bundled up as an expression that is then sent to the entity framework to be executed in the database.

Entity framework will make an SQL query from that expression, which returns the ten rows from the table, which the `ToList` methods reads and places in a `List<T>` where `T` is the type of the items in the `ALLOCATION_D` collection.