# Using entity framework and MSSQL AVG() function

Tags: sql, c, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, average

I have this line of code (using `MSSQL`):

```
double avg = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.RecordDate < today).Select(z => z.value).Average();
```

I wonder if this is translated to `SQL` `AVG()` function or the `Average()` run on client side ?

This table contains 50,000 records per day and I prefer to let the database calculate the average and pass back only a single value.

And, how can I see the `SQL` query sent to the database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't enumerate your `queryable`, yes, `average` will be done on db side.

You can also simplify your code. Select is not needed, there's an overload for average taking an `Expression<Func<T, double>>` (or a decimal, int...) as parameter.

```
double avg = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.RecordDate < today).Average(z => z.value);
```

and they are quite many ways to see the sql generated, you can google for `sql generated linq`, or take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899974/how-to-view-linq-generated-sql-statements), for example