# Where to find translated Linq to Entity query to Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I want to get the translated Linq query programmatically and do some stuff with that Sql syntax.

Suppose this is my code:

```
public class MyApiController:ApiController
{
   public IQueryable<object> Get()
   {
      var objs=Context.Objexts.Where(m=>m.Id>10);
      return objs;
   }
}
```

I want to find and get the Sql syntax like:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Objexts where Id > 10
```

Comment: Don't get what you want to do. Why get the SQL query generated from a Linq?

Comment: Yeah also don't get why you want to do that, you can set up the query with code, why do you want to alter the actual query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the `ToString()` method on `objs`. This will result in a call to the `ToTraceString` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) that returns the executed SQL:

```
string sql = objs.ToString();
```

Comment: Will the sql returned from ToString always be a complete sql statement without parameters? If I use .Where(c => c == "abc'; delete from othertable;"), will the resulting sql be guaranteed to be sql injection safe?

Comment: Such a trivial but important concept. Half of the times we will start sql query profile to get hold of the query text getting fired on the sql server instance. Sweet!

Comment: If objs=Context.Objexts.Where(m=>m.Id>10).Sum(m=>m.num), than how to know translated sql @Jaco?

Answer (score 7):

another option if you are using Entity Framework 6 is use the new feature to logging whats is happen, you can get the t-sql and the query time:

[Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx)

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; //here, you can write this info to a text file for example.

    // Your code here... 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think these posts may help you:

1) [How to view LINQ Generated SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899974/how-to-view-linq-generated-sql-statements)

2) [How do I view the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)

Couple of examples (from the above):

```
var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)objs).ToTraceString();
var sql = objs.ToString();
```

Documentation on `.ToTraceString()` can be found here:

[MSDN trace string documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring(v=vs.110).aspx)