# LINQ to SQL Quick conversion to compiled query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

We have hundreds of LINQ to SQL calls and are encountering performance problem due to compilation. Migrating to EF6 is not an option. Is there a quick way like setting that can be used to produce compiled query instead of rewriting static methods with CompiledQuery.Compile? I couldn't find such an option. Just wanted to check before rewriting all.

Comment: This was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899974/how-to-view-linq-generated-sql-statements I hope this helps

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but are you sure converting all to complied is going to solve the issue? Atwood had a really good blog post about this: https://blog.codinghorror.com/compiled-or-bust/

Comment: Calls that take 800ms occasionally take 2s! Drill down using AppDynamics show slowness due to two reasons: opening SQL connection & LINQ compilation. We are looking at setting the min pool size to 20 or higher to address the first issue.