# How to approach querying a parent table based on values in a child table and a child tables related data table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, linq

Context: I have a parent table (Product), a child table (Transactions), and a child data table (RelatedData).

[image: Tables]

A Product has many transactions.  Transactions of type 'A' have a RelatedData entry with SpecialData.

I would like to get all Product records that have their **LAST** transaction of type 'A' with the SpecialData value of 'B'

I'm using linq to SQL on a MSSQL database.

```
var data = from p in db.Product
           select p;

//various filters
    data = data.Where(...);
```

What I have right now for the query I want to implement:

```
data = data.Where(p=> p.Transactions
                            .Where(t => p.ProductID == t.ProductID && 
                                        t.TransType == 'A') 
                            .OrderByDescending(t => t.DateTime)
                            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.RelatedData //Get latest
                                                     .Single().SpecialData == 'B')
                        != null
                    );
```

It isn't returning any of the test data I've got set up in the database. Please help.

Comment: Don't you need a JOIN?

Comment: Well, have you tried simplifying any of the queries and debugging it? find out where and what data is returned and go from there?

Comment: Split it into several queries and check on which step you are filtering out what shouldn't be filtered out

Comment: If it's too complex in LINQ, try writing a Stored Procedure to get the desired results.

Comment: @RyanWilson ORMs don't need joins, *they* generate the join statements from the entity relations. The entities are related through the `Transactions` collection. Which means `p.ProductID == t.ProductID` is pointless btw

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Interesting how that works, thanks for the info. I don't use ORMs as I prefer doing the database design myself. Along with the Stored Procs, Views, etc.

Comment: @DaltonRussel please provide the classes, table schema and test data. Don't force people to write everything from scratch in order to test the code.

Comment: @RyanWilson ORMs aren't related to database design either, they with map *objects* to relational tables. Hence the acronym Object Relational Mapping. You can map objects to views, which is probably easier in this case - a ROW_NUMBER() would return the last entry immediatelly while there's no way to specify this in LINQ

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good point. Seems I need to read up on ORMs, I just don't see how using an ORM and LINQ is easier than just writing a stored procedure that could do what the person is asking for.

Comment: One way to debug is to put the profiler against the database and see the query issued against the database. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899974/how-to-view-linq-generated-sql-statements) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is:

> I would like to get all Product records that have their LAST
>   transaction of type 'A' with the SpecialData value of 'B'

From your requirement I understand that the key is to find the last transaction of each product.

Assuming your entities are like this:

```
public class Product
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        public int TransId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        public string TransType { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        public virtual RelatedData RelatedData  { get;set;}
    }

    public class RelatedData
    {
        public int TransId { get; set; }
        public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
        public string SpecialData { get; set; }

    }
```

between Transaction and Related data is one to one relation.

Than you can do it like this:

```
  //last transaction for each product
            var transactions = db.Transactions.GroupBy(x =>x.Product)
                .SelectMany(a =>a.Where(b=>b.DateTime==a.Max(c=>c.DateTime)));
            //last transaction of TransType A
            var transA = transactions.Where(x => x.TransType == "A");

        //where SpecialData is B

        var transSpecialDataB = transA.Where(x => x.RelatedData.SpecialData == "B");

        //now you need to get your products
        var products = transSpecialDataB.Select(x => x.Product).ToList();
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, without any data to test it out.

```
data = data.Where(p=> p.Transactions
                            .Any(t => t.TransType == 'A' && 
                                 t => t.RelatedData.FirstOrDefault().SpecialData == 'B') 
                 );
```

Notice that you don't need `t => p.ProductID == t.ProductID` because all `Transactions` should be related to that `Product`.

I am using `FirstOrDefault()` here because it seems like it could return more than 1 result. If you were to use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` on a sequence with more than one element, it throws an exception.