# Traditional sql equivalent for Linq functions

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I wrote this query, but I want to use it with functions.

```
var hede = (from customer in _customerRepository.Table
            join source in _sourcedefinitionepository.Table on customer.SouceCode equals source.SourceCode
            join branch in _branchdefinitionepository.Table on customer.BranchCode equals branch.BranchCode
            where customer.SirketKod == 1 && source.UretimKanali == "E"
            select new { Customer = customer, SourceName = source.LongName, branch.BranchName});
```

How can I join 3 tables, how can I convert this code?

```
var query = _customerRepository.Table.Join() ... Select()...
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899974/how-to-view-linq-generated-sql-statements

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ?

Comment: Do you want to write it using lambda expressions?

Comment: I thought your question is roughly "how to see SQL generated by LINQ query"... Probably I misunderstood the post. Sorry.

Comment: No i just want to write my query with using functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in this way

```
var result2Tables = _customerRepository.Table.Join(_sourcedefinitionepository.Table, c => c.SouceCode , s => s.SourceCode,
                (c, s) => new
                {
                    Customer = c, 
                    SourceName = s
                })).Where(p => p.Customer.SirketKod == 1 && p.SourceName .UretimKanali == "E")

var result = result2Tables.Join(_branchdefinitionepository.Table, p => p.Customer.BranchCode, b => b.BranchCode, (r, b) => new 
   {
      Customer = r, 
      SourceName = r.SourceName.LongName, 
      b.BranchName 
   })
```